# mimer sql - create new table with average price

Tags: sql, mimer-sql

Create a new table that contains all items that cost more than the average.

My previous queries:

```
CREATE VIEW AveragePrice AS SELECT * FROM Item
WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM Item);

SELECT * FROM item
WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM item);
```

Now I want to create table and insert same data as above to the new table in one query..mimer sql

Comment: Mimer SQL has no such functionality. You have to do it in two steps. (First `CREATE TABLE`, then `INSERT INTO table SELECT ...`.) But why store same values twice?!? I'd keep the VIEW solution - and avoid data redundancy, and also prevent data inconsistency (which is always the risk when storing data dependent on other table data, such as AVG(price).)

Answer (score -1):

```
 create table newTab as 
 SELECT * FROM item
 WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM item);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it gives me error: 1: create table AveragePrice2 as SELECT * FROM item WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price) FROM item)
                              ^
Mimer SQL error -12104 in function PREPARE
         Invalid construction